# How can I fix this graphical/rendering issue with the installer on my system?

Tags: release-freya

When I boot into elementary OS all the windows are messed up like this. I tried re-downloading the OS and nothing changed.

[image: broken installer]

Comment: Are you using a CD drive or an USB drive? From which operating system have you mounted elementary's `.iso` file? Which tool did you use to mount it? You got to be a lot more descriptive if you want us to help you out.

Comment: I'm using a 3.0 usb, mounted the iso on Win10, and the tool I used was Universal USB installer 1.9.6.1

Comment: Well, elementary OS [suggests you](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#choose-operating-system) to use Rufus on Windows. Also, check the hash of the `.iso` file before you try to mount it to a USB device. I _think_ that this is the problem. IIRC the same happened to me (although during the beta stage like 6 months ago).

Comment: Okay, I'll try Rufus and check the hash

Comment: It looks more like a graphic driver issue.

Comment: How would I go about fixing a graphics driver issue on elementary

Comment: What graphics chip/card do you use?

Comment: You can also use PowerISO tool to create a bootable usb from windows. Tested on a dell inspiron 15 AMD laptop, works fine.

Comment: Maybe bad VRAM.Does M$ Windows work